# conway game error with 2d array manipulation

Tags: c++

So I'm working on the [life game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), and so far I have come up with this http://ideone.com/QG4tsS I'm not sure exactly if I am on the right track or not. Basically I have a function putting out random values to try and test my code. But nothing seems to happen. I suspect my problem lies with the following code

```
int sum = 0;

    for (int k = (i - 1); k <= (i + 1); k++) {
        for (int l = (j - 1); l <= (j + 1); l++) {
            sum += currentGen[k][l];
        }
    }

    return sum;
```

So my result gives me a 2d array with all 0's but shouldn't I start to see some changes and patterns starting to form? I get one 1 and the rest are 0.

Output

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What was the input to this loop?  ie. was was the previous generation that you are scanning to create `currentGen`?  And presumably there's a pair of loops around these two... can you show the whole function?

Comment: well i created a function `RandomCells` to add 1's see here http://ideone.com/QG4tsS

Comment: You should also check if i-1, i+1, j-1, j+1 are within the range of your 2D array.

Comment: You are not outputting the sum values. You are outputting the array values after getting processed by your Conway function. I suggest you use a debugger to checkout the sum values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide this answer based on the code you posted at http://ideone.com/QG4tsS .  You really should consider adding that code to your original question, so that future folks who find this on StackOverflow have the full context.

Your `RandomCells` function only sets cells to 1 if they meet the `RANDOM` threshold.  It doesn't clear them to 0 otherwise.  Once you fix that, you'll be all set.  ie.

```
void RandomCells(int currentGen[][CELLY]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CELLX; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < CELLY; j++) {
            if (rand() % 100 + 1 < RANDOM) {
                currentGen[i][j] = 1;
            } else
            {
                currentGen[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without that `else` clause, I was seeing initial generations that looked like this:

```
0 0 4196155 1 
1813657216 1 4197653 0 
-870503576 1 4197584 1
```

Clearly, most of those cells were non-zero, and so Conway's Life algorithm would map them to 0 in the next generation because of "crowding".

The reason `currentGen` was filled with such 'random' values is that it was allocated as an *automatic* variable to `main`.  *Automatic* variables do not get initialized to any particular value.  You need to initialize them yourself.  You can do that by modifying your algorithm (as I did above), or by adding an explicit bit of code to initialize the structure.

This differs from file-scope variables, which C and C++ define as initialized-to-zero on program start if they don't have initializers or default constructors.  (Pedants will point out that even *that* has caveats.)

Once you make the required fixes, to truly see Conway's Life, you'll need to set `CELLX` and `CELLY` to larger values...